# Python - How to print variable outside for loop. Name 'word' can be undefined

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new on python how can I print the variable outside the for loop?

Here's my code thanks:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.morewords.com/contains/' + "hi")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

words = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'word-box-link'})[random.randint(0, 8)]
for tag in words:
    word = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', tag.string.strip())
print(word)
```

This is not working:

```
print(word)
```

But when I place it inside the for loop, it's working. How to make it work outside?

Comment: `word = ""` before loop.

Comment: What is the point of assigning to `word` over and over in a loop?  Only the final iteration of the loop has any effect, the results of all previous iterations are simply overwritten.  Perhaps you want to append the results to a list, so that you have *all* of them available afterwards.

Comment: `Name 'word' can be undefined` That doesn't sound like a python error.  Where is that message coming from exactly?  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: what do you think might happen if the `soup.find_all()` operation finds nothing? this is most likely what's happening here. no iteration of the for loop occurs, and nothing is ever assigned to `word`.

Comment: If nothing gets assigned to 'word', he’d be receiving an error stating it’s undefined. He’s not receiving an error.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `word` is only defined when the program at sometime would enter the for loop. If the for loop has never been iterated, of course, `word` is not defined and you would encounter runtime error. The best practice should be

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.morewords.com/contains/' + "hi")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

words = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'word-box-link'})[random.randint(0, 8)]
word = None

for tag in words:
    word = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', tag.string.strip())
print(word)
```

Comment: best practice according to what? what does this answer accomplish other than avoiding the error?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. It prints nothing.

Comment: @helpthenoob, it prints an empty string, which is exactly the correct output based on the logic, regardless if word is assigned an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

It actual does work outside of the loop. The problem is that after each iteration, it overwrites the `word` variable. The very last iteration is a string of whitespace `' '`, which you use `.strip()` to give you `''`. When you print that, it appears as not working, put it's actually printing that empty string.

```
IPdb [7]: word
''
```

When it's in the loop, it's printing this list:

```
['\n        accomplishing', '31', ' ']
```

However you remove the whitespace before and after, and you also have a regex that removes any non letters (which is why the `'31'` appears not to print with the loop either). So really when it's in the loop, it's printing:

```
['accomplishing', '', '']
```

Which is why you see:

```
abrachias
```

followed by 2 blank/empty string lines under it. See image bellow where I highlighted it:

[image]